# onCreate() method is not called

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have a gridView as seen here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_drag_and_drop_app"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00FF00">

            <!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Search_applications"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvApps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
/>
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToPersonalize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/Personalize"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<GridView 
android:id="@+id/GRIDVIEW1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
 >  

</GridView>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/trash_can"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/trashcanDescription_Delete"
    android:padding="40dip"
    android:src="@drawable/trashcan"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then have the coding set up in my GridView.java:

```
public class GridView extends Activity {    
private int draggedIndex = -1;
private BaseAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    Log.d("GridView", "onCreate called");
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);

 android.widget.GridView gridView = (android.widget.GridView) findViewById(R.id.GRIDVIEW1);

    // Instance of Adapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));

}
```

And then have the adapter in another class here:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;
IMPORTS

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContextGV;

// Keep all Images in array list
public ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Constructor
public GridViewAdapter(Context c){
    mContextGV = c;
}

@Override
// How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
public int getCount() {
    return drawables.size();
}

@Override
// Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
// data set
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drawables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(mContextGV);
    }

    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}

}
```

And my Maniest set as so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff"/>

</receiver>

<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.WidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>

</intent-filter> 

</activity>   

<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Drag_and_Drop_App" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AppInfoAdapter" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Feedback" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.GridView" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.SendMessageActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Utilities" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.Personalize" android:label="@string/app_name" ></activity>
<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.SwipeDetector" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

However, when I run my program and get to the Drag_and_Drop_App layout (the layout shown above), the onCreate of the gridView is never called and therefore the images never show up. I've double checked everything and haven't been able to figure out why it is not showing up.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a way to GridView activity to be launched. There is no indication how you did started the GridView activity.

Comment: I was not aware of this. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: After registering the Activity in Manifest file you have to start that activity by using startActivity somewhere in your code.

Comment: So can I use startActivity in my onCreate() method of my Drag_and_Drop_App class so that it starts the gridView?

Comment: No no. Here is the thing in usual case we create an application where there will be an entry point for an application.And that entry point is an Activity with <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> in it's manifest. But as i am seeing you are building/running an application for appwidget. It is a totally different case. This app has no entry point until user puts your widget to home screen.For appwidget you will find awesome documentation in developer.android.com.

Comment: Ok so what can I do? I'm aware taht the setup for an appwidget is different so I can't use the normal entry point, but then how can I use the startActivity option as you said above?

Comment: In here your AppWidgetProvider class is AFBWidget, it will be called as soon as user add the widget to devices home screen. And that is actually your way through the project.

Answer (score 0):

if GridView is the first activity of your app, you have to add an intent filter in your manifest declaration :

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.GridView"             android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: Since my app is set up as an appWidget, this didn't work. I tried this on both my GridView activity and the activity that the gridView appears on and it didn't work